# How to convert from GeoTIFF to PNG/JPG and Web Mercator in Java?

Tags: raster, convert, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I'd like to convert raster image from (geo)tiff to an  png/jpg and afterwards if it is necessary ... I'd like to convert the coordinates with help of EPSG-Codes to the OSM/Google Projection(EPSG: 3857/ 900913). All this i'm doing with java programming.
Anyone a good hint... like an java libary??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) should be able to do all of that - either natively or through the GDAL bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Could [cs-map](http://trac.osgeo.org/csmap/) help? You would need to check it can do raster though. Here's a [user guide](http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/csmap/trunk/CsMapDev/Documentation/Preliminary%20CS-MAP%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf) (PDF)